# quadratic variation and local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, isometry

Consider a predictable process $H_t$ and a continuous local  martingale $M_t$ for $t \in [0,T]$

I want to show that $$X_t:=\left(\int_0^t H_s dM_s\right)^2 - \int_0^t H^2_s d \langle M_s\rangle $$ is a local martingale. When I take a localizing sequence $\{\tau_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$,  $\int_0^t H_s d(M_s\wedge \tau_k)$ is a square integrable martingale. Ito-isometry state that

$$E\left[\left(\int_0^t H_s d(M_s\wedge \tau_k\right)^2\right] =E\left[ \int_0^t H_s^2  d\langle M_s \wedge \tau_k\rangle\right] $$

Therefore taking the expectation in the first equation, I get $E[X_{t\wedge \tau_k}]=0$

Therefore $E[X_{t \wedge \tau_k}]= E[X_0]=0$

Optinal sampling states that then $X_{t \wedge \tau_k}$ is martingale and hence $X_t$ a local martingale.
Am I right?

Comment: Why does $\mathbb{E}[X_{t \wedge \tau_k}] = \mathbb{E}[X_0]$ imply $X^{\tau_k}$ is a martingale?

Comment: @user6247850: Optinal sampling states that : If $E[M(\tau)]=E[M(0)]=0$ holds  for a stopping $\tau$, then $M$ is martingale.

Comment: Right, but you only showed it for a fixed time $t$ rather than for a stopping time.  Your proof is still basically correct, just wanted to point out you need a stopping time there.

Comment: @user6247850: Then you for your remark. But how can I show it for a stopping time. Replace every t by $\tau$?

Comment: Yes, that should do it!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alif . The version of the optional sampling theorem that I am aware of [Karatzas &Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* p.19] implies that, for a continuous martingale $M$ and a stopping time $\tau\,,$ we have $E[M(\tau)]=E[M(0)]\,.$ What reference states the converse ?

Comment: @KurtG.: I have no rerference for that. We proved that  in the lecture.

Comment: @Alif : can you reproduce that proof here ? Or at least scetch it ? As far as I know it is a totally non standard result most likely making other assumptions than just a continuous process $M$ that has $E[M(\tau)]=E[M(0)]$ for all stopping times. I never heard before that this makes $M$ a martingale.